# OS X: How can I automatically connect to a non-broadcasted wireless network

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, macbook

Every time I open my MacBook, I am forced to go to Join Other Network, then type in the Network Name, and select the Security type. I check the box for remember this network and it remembers my username/password after I type in the name and security. There has to be a way for it to automatically connect to this network even though it isn't broadcast, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your MacBook is designed to remember networks to which you connect and look for them in the future even if the SSID is not broadcasted.

To examine and clear your list of remembered networks, go to System Preferences, then Network, select your AirPort interface on the left, then click "Advanced".  You can add a network here, including security settings.  If you already see your network, try deleting it and re-adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You might check your keychain or your remembered networks to see if something might be interfering with your auto-joining of a WiFi network, because what you describe that you want is exactly how it works for me.